# How can I use the NUMPAD_PERIOD function to focus on an object when I'm on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: shortcut, osx

I already know that you can emulate the number pad through the User Preferences, but that only seems to provide the numbers **0-9**. I'm trying to focus on an object by pressing **.** ,however nothing seems to happen. I've heard about KeyRemap4MacBook, but it isn't available for Sierra.

Comment: *File > User Preferences > Input > 3D View > 3D view Global* customize it to your heart's content

Comment: cool thanks, and I can even further customize it :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to emulate the numpad <kbd>.</kbd> is to go to blenders * User Preferences > Input*.

Then in the search field type "show active" and remap the function to a key you don't/won't use.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the "View -> Frame Selected", then "Add to Quick Favourites". This will add this function to the quick list. The quick list is available by `q` shortcut.

Also, the "Frame Selected" item has a shortcut `f`, so I can quickly use `qf` to focus on the object.

Comment: That's clever, thank you. Much cleaner than remapping